one-time-password alt_SMS_autofill permission in flutter
I used alt_SMS_autofill for OTP verfication
google reject my app many times (29 release) with differanrt changes
I select in google form once SMS , Collected and call_OTP
and permission in manifest
"send,  receive, read"
he asked me to remove permission
I remove all permission then use send only or read only
i make all differanrt   isue can do
all rejected
what the wrong what i used in manifest and in google form in need SMS for OTP only
thanks
I use in manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

then
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/> 

then
<uses-permission``android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/> 

<uses-permission``android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>  

<uses-permission``android:name="android.permission.send_SMS"/>

with google form
SMS,Collected,call_OTP
or
SMS,Collected,defult SMS
and I try to remove all permission in manifest
and clear SMS From Google Form
I used all possibilities and permutations to make it work All rejected
but
when I removed the alt_SMS_autofill google accept the app??
what can i do to use autofill OTP
